# Protractor override "beforeAll" http mock

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor, integration-testing

I'm using Protractor in order to get some End-to-End testing in my application. In a test, I mock the backend-calls with a MockModule as following:

```
describe('Lets test a feature' , function(){
    beforeAll(function () {
        var customerE2E = function () {
            angular.module('customerE2E', ['customer', 'ngMockE2E'])
                .run(function ($httpBackend) {

                    $httpBackend.whenPOST('/api/data').respond(200);
                    $httpBackend.whenGET(/^.*/).passThrough();
            });
        };
        browser.addMockModule('customerE2E', customerE2E);
    });

    it('correctly demonstrates my problem', function () {
        expect(element(by.css('h4')).getText()).toMatch('Hello world');
    }    
})
```

This works really good but my problem is that I also want to test my application when the post responds with a 404, 500 etc. I have solved this by having a new "describe"-function for each case but it would be nice to just be able to override this call from inside the "it"-functions.

```
it('correctly demonstrates my problem', function () {
    expect(element(by.css('h4')).getText()).toMatch('Hello world');
}

it('show error due to bad request', function () {
    /* 
     Replace $httpBackend.whenPOST('/api/data').respond(200);
     with $httpBackend.whenPOST('/api/data').respond(404);
    */
    expect(element(by.css('h4')).getText()).toMatch('Failed api call');
}
```

I'm really new to this so I am wondering if there is a nice way to achieve an easy way to override the earlier MockModuled that was set in the beforeAll-function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `beforeEach()` to achieve it.

```
describe('Test Mock Module',function () {

    var statusCodes = [200,404,500];
    var currentTestNumber = 0;
    beforeAll(function () {
        var customerE2E = function () {
            angular.module('customerE2E', ['customer', 'ngMockE2E'])
                .run(function ($httpBackend) {

                    $httpBackend.whenPOST('/api/data').respond(200);
                    $httpBackend.whenGET(/^.*/).passThrough();
                });
        };
        browser.addMockModule('customerE2E', customerE2E);
    });

    /*Below method will be executed before each test and set the required response respectively*/
    beforeEach(function () {
        $httpBackend.whenPOST('/api/data').respond(statusCodes[currentTestNumber++]);
    });

    it('test 200 status code',function () {
        expect(element(by.css('h4')).getText()).toMatch('Message for 200 status code');
    });

    it('test 404 status code',function () {
        expect(element(by.css('h4')).getText()).toMatch('Message for 404 status code');
    });

    it('test 500 status code',function () {
        expect(element(by.css('h4')).getText()).toMatch('Message for 500 status code');
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you even tried this? I can't neither reach $httpBakend from beforeEeach since it's used within a module. This can be solved by creating a new customerE2E in beforeEech but that's seems ugly and I also can't reach the variables statusCodes and CurrentTestNumber